# how to list age wise result from DATETIME data

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have an application in PHP, MYSQL wherein I have persons database 
where their date of birth is recorded under
birthday column as DATETIME entry.

I want to know how to list profiles age wise?
e.g. If I want to list persons whose age is between 27 years and 31 years only
birthday DATETIME 
I have a form post data like this

```
$_POST['age_from'];//say 27
$_POST['age_upto'];// say 31
```

What will be SQL query be like?

```
@mysql_query("Select * from persons where age is ");
// but I don't have age column
// What are possibilities without adding age column?
// IF I add age column then How to automatically update it
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any extra columns.

Simply use,

```
SELECT * FROM persons 
WHERE FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthday )), "%Y")+0 >= 27
AND   FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthday )), "%Y")+0 <= 31
```